# How reset my private key in heroku?

Tags: git, heroku, ssh

I want to do a "Git push heroku master" but it says: that i have to enter the password to unlock the private key, but I completely forgot the password. Is there any way to reset my password or something?

Answer (score 1):

You did `heroku keys:clear`, which revoke all the old keys you’re no longer using, but, did you also run `ssh-keygen -t rsa` before `heroku keys:add` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can only change the private key passphrase if you know the current one. If you don't, then you have to generate a new key.

Comment: I aready used `heroku keys:clear` and deleted all the keys in my computer, and i did `herkou keys:add` and created a new one, but what do i have to do after that?